# Cant send mail to @gmail

Tags: php, email

I have this code for sending mail

```
$to = "account@gmail.com";
$subject = "mail title";
$message = "mail content";

$from_mail = "sender@site.com";          

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n'.
           'From: '.$from_mail.'' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: '.$from_mail.'' . "\r\n" .
           'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

This code sends mails  for any mail provider except `@gmail`.

What may be reason for this

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't end up in the spam?

Comment: @ gd1, no in the spam also.

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi: Nope, not a duplicate. He's trying to send *to* GMail not *from*.

Comment: conatct with your hosting support as some of them may have blocked this settings of sending mail to some specified mailing services or may be they are checking whaether that mail exist or not before sending it.

Comment: Why so much hate from the votes? He clearly shows research effort (`This code sends mails for any mail provider except @gmail`) and even provides us with most of the code that fails. Can you show us the function that actually sends the code, @OTARIKI?

Comment: Balanced unnecessary downvotes

Comment: @OTARIKI is this is running at your development environment or it is arising at time of hosting ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021655/php-mail-function-will-not-send-to-gmail-but-will-send-to-my-non-gmail-account?rq=1 Here he says gmail blocked the mail, cause some account on the same shared hosting server was used for spam, if you do not use `localhost`.

Comment: Is "sender@site.com" the actual email from value you are using? That does not look like a real email address (to me) and could be your issue - along the lines suggested by Youn Elan in his answer. You need to make sure that the from email address isn't something quite obviously spam-a-licious.

Comment: @JakeGould I agree with you , But At one time i was stucked in similar kind of problem while hosting the site on a live server env. At that time they told us that we have blocked some mail providers due to spam check, So I suggested here.

Comment: @JakeGould ,yes that's why I marked your comment useful :)

Comment: One possible solution, that will ensure the absolute fastest mechanism for receiving your emails in "@gmail" domain is to use [Gmail as your SMTP server](http://lifehacker.com/111166/how-to-use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server). That will require using SMTP authentication, and having a gmail account.

Answer (score 3):

My guess—as is others—is that your message went to a SPAM folder.  But it is unclear what machine this script is on. Is this your localhost test environment or another isolated development server? Or is it a functioning production server?

If this is a localhost or other isolated test environment, my guess is that Gmail—and possibly even AOL—are blocking your mail as potential SPAM.

But if this is a forward facing production server, the problem can most likely traced to a missing PTR (aka: Reverse DNS record) for the IP address the machine is on.

As explained [on this site](http://hosting.intermedia.net/support/kb/?id=1317).

> PTR records are mainly used to check if the server name is actually
>   associated with the IP address from where the connection was
>   initiated.

Meaning, many mail servers are setup to simply mark any message as SPAM if they cannot connect a valid PTR record to the domain.

Also, if this is a production server with multiple IP addresses, there might be an issue with your SPF (Sender Policy Framework) record. Read up more [on this site](http://www.openspf.org/Introduction):

> Even more precisely, SPFv1 allows the owner of a domain to specify
>   their mail sending policy, e.g. which mail servers they use to send
>   mail from their domain.

So an SPF record is a DNS record that basically says: “Okay, you think you are an e-mail from `xyz.com` IP address `1.2.3.4`? Let me look up your SPF record, and hey! The SPF record says that any e-mail sent from the IP address of `1.2.3.4` is cool with `xyz.com`! You are not SPAM.”

While there are other factors such as delays in delivery or receipt when dealing with e-mails, I am pretty confident resolving the PTR and the SPF status of the IP address you are sending from will clear this up. This is not a coding issue but a networking and mail infrastructure configuration issue on your side.

Answer (score 2):

Because of spam, email providers are getting more and more stringent about accepting mail.

If you are using shared hosting, then probably that email server will have a bad reputation and you may have to change provider or use whatever mail service they provide. emailing support may be a good start

Many times, mail is not completely blocked but delayed. I would wait a while and check if email gets there. I would also check the mail queue and see what the status of the email is

make sure that you have the appropriate DNS records:
_ dkim
_ spf
_ dmarc

Make sure that reverse dns is setup and that the ip is not in a blocked pool,

Also, make sure you are not on any block list.

IP reputations matter and get improved over time.

Comment: I would add that, as it doesn't appear that any authentication information is being setup, that he appears to be using the `mail()` function or some other one that sends from the system's default account. There's a good chance gmail is wholesale blocking it.

Comment: Good point though it all depends on his config. If he has a dedicated box which blocks relaying, it would be ok to use the default mail.