# PHP: Gmail ignoring any email I send it via mail()

Tags: php, email, gmail

When using the below code I am able to send (and receive) email to my **Yahoo** account, but when sending to my **Gmail** account, nothing shows up
  (and yes, I have monitored the Spam folder for over 4hrs - nothing!).

```
    public function sendEmail($email_addy, $temp_pass)
    {
        $website_name = $this->website_name;

        $message = <<<MESSAGE
        Greetings!

        Your password is:
        $temp_pass

        Your friends at: $website_name !

MESSAGE;

        $headers = 'From: ' . $this->email_from . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $this->email_from . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion ();

        mail ( $email_addy, $this->email_subject, $message, $headers );
    }
```

Any ideas why Gmail just deletes the email? I thought that the message body text might be too small so I even added to the message with no different results...

Comment: Try removing `\r` from headers variable

Comment: OT: I hope you do not really try to send a password in clear text via email, so readable for everyone!

Comment: Use PHPMailer/SwiftMail and a proper smtp gateway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP mail() function will not send to gmail but will send to my non-gmail account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021655/php-mail-function-will-not-send-to-gmail-but-will-send-to-my-non-gmail-account)

Comment: @Lepanto, will try that now (Edit: nope, didnt work). arkascha, the password is not important enough to spend much time on security :) Mario, thanks will have a look at that as well!